# Updating HTML appended items with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create updating Jquery appended HTML items...

Added items get increased variable `x` and used for the HTML attribute `name`, when one item removed and another one added... as you can see, the older item which was already outputted, stays with the same id and creates duplicates...

[image: UI screenshoot]

How to update the id of items, if one was removed, to keep the right chronological order?

Here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gensus/xpvt214o/394771/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 3; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="' + x + '" placeholder="#' + x + '"/><a href="#" class="remove">X</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="add">Add</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="1" placeholder="#1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons why incremental attributes is an anti-pattern. Use a common name on all the elements and deal with the value as an array when it's sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to renumber them

Note I use the number of inputs to count them.

I also ONLY change the placeholder, not the field content if any.

```js
function reNum() {
  $(".inp").each(function(i) {
    this.name = (i + 1)
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "#" + (i + 1));
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 3; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var $wrapper = $(".wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  $(".add").click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(".inp").length;
    if (x >= max_fields) return;
    x++;
    $wrapper.append('<div><input class="inp" type="text" name="' + x + '" placeholder="#' + x + '"/><a href="#" class="remove">X</a></div>');
  });

  $wrapper.on("click", ".remove", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    reNum();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="add">Add</button>
  <div><input class="inp" type="text" name="1" placeholder="#1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="txt"><input type="text" name="' + x + '" placeholder="#' + x + '"/><a href="#" class="remove">X</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    var count = $('.txt').length;
    $('.txt').remove();
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      var template = '<div class="txt"><input type="text" name="' + i + '" placeholder="#' + i + '"/>'
      if (i > 1)
        template += '<a href="#" value=' + i + ' class="remove">X</a>'
      template += '</div>'
      $(wrapper).append(template);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="add">Add</button>
  <div class="txt"><input type="text" name="1" placeholder="#1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code, unlike mine will remove all content already entered when deleting something

Comment: Thank's, it's close to what I'm looking for - it solves the problem, counters used to create dynamic content, which is nested in removable elements... but, not so easy to edit/maintain.